# How can I make integer to display in window?

Tags: winapi, calculator

I want to have in window something like:

```
int a;
cout<<a;
```

but I don't know how I can do it. At the beginning, I want to have number displayed on screen and have a button which adds +1 and another button which adds -1 to this number. I want this number to be updated without next compilation. Do you know how I can do it?

I want it to be a prototype of simple calculator.

Comment: You are asking how to create a GUI app. That's far too broad. Read Petzold's book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your calculation in your corresponding button handler and set the "screen's" text with [SetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

The idea is following:

You have 2 buttons-one to add and one to subtract. You can create them in your `WM_CREATE` handler like this:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HWND btnAdd = CreateWindowEx( 0, L"Button", 
                     L"+1", //this is the text for your adding button
                     WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                     50, 150, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)8004, hInst, 0 );

        HWND btnSubtract = CreateWindowEx( 0, L"Button", 
                     L"-1", //this is the text for your adding button
                     WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                     50, 250, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)8005, hInst, 0 );

        // since you want "calculator type" application
        // here is your result window-edit control

        HWND input = CreateWindowEx( 0, L"Edit", 
                     L"", // no need for text
                     WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_NUMBER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                     50, 450, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)8006, hInst, 0 );

        HWND result = CreateWindowEx( 0, L"Edit", 
                     L"", // no need for text
                     WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_READONLY | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                     50, 450, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)8007, hInst, 0 );

        // other stuff

    }
    return 0L;
```

After user clicks on your buttons you set text of the `result` edit control with `SetWindowText` like this in your `WM_COMMAND` handler:

```
case 8004: // add 1 to the number
    {
        // get the number from input edit control
        wchar_t temp[10];
        GetWindowText( GetDlgItem( hWnd, 8006 ), temp, 10 );   

        //convert text to nubmer
        int InputedNumber = wtoi( temp );

        // show the result in the result edit control
        memset( temp, L'\0', sizeof(temp) ); //reuse variable to save memory
        swprintf_s( temp, 10, L"%d", InputNumber+1 ); //convert result to text
        SetWindowText( GetDlgItem( hWnd, 8007 ), temp ); //show the result
    }
case 8005: // subtract 1 to the number
    {
        // get the number from input edit control
        wchar_t temp[10];
        GetWindowText( GetDlgItem( hWnd, 8006 ), temp, 10 );   

        //convert text to number
        int InputedNumber = wtoi( temp );

        // show the result in the result edit control
        memset( temp, L'\0', sizeof(temp) ); //reuse variable to save memory
        swprintf_s( temp, 10, L"%d", InputNumber-1 ); //convert result to text
        SetWindowText( GetDlgItem( hWnd, 8007 ), temp ); //show the result
    }
```

Above were relevant code snippets for `C++`.

This might be a big bite for you to handle, so I recommend you to go through [this beginner tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/).

Good luck and best regards!